# Christian priest discovers aliens are God's new chosen

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I probably read this short story or novella in the 70s-80s but I think it could have been pretty old then.

The Earth has been invaded by aliens. The aliens are pretty horrible people, violent, blood-thirsty, tearing people limb from limb and eating them and that sort of thing.

The MC is a sincere and devout Christian priest or minister who had been sheltering people and telling them to trust in God and such platitudes.

Somehow he ends up with some human fighters near an alien encampment. They spy on the encampment and are shocked to see the aliens invoke Yahweh, who appears and encourages the invaders.

The MC is horrified at the unarguable truth that his God has chosen a new Chosen People and is now the enemy of mankind.

He is forced to reassess his entire life and decides to side with the rebels and do all he can to fight God.

Comment: [For I am a Jealous People](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164081/story-in-which-god-is-on-the-side-of-aliens-invading-earth).  It's a classic Lester del Ray story! The answer to the question I've linked gives extensive quotes from the story so you'll easily be able to tell if it's the one you're remembering.If this is the story please let us know and we'll mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Oh yes, that IS the one. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I've just realised that other answer was never accepted so I can't mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @JohnRennie It was accepted as a comment (just like this one) so it's  OK.

Answer (score 11):

This is [For I Am a Jealous People](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41391) as described (in great detail) in [user14111's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/164106/4144) to [Story in which God is on the side of aliens invading earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164081/story-in-which-god-is-on-the-side-of-aliens-invading-earth). Also the subject of [Short story from the 70s(?) about aliens/angels destroying humankind, from the point of view of a priest/pastor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223288/short-story-from-the-70s-about-aliens-angels-destroying-humankind-from-the-p).